# Map exception in completable future to a different exception type?

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I'm using java 8's completable futures and I'd like to be able take an exception that is throwing by the future and transform it to a different exception.

All the composite stuff I've tried seems to get short circuited once an exception occurs.

Using a scala future, for example, I can do something like this:

```
scala.concurrent.Future<Object> translatedException = ask.recover(new Recover<Object>() {
            @Override public Object recover(final Throwable failure) throws Throwable {
                if (failure instanceof AskTimeoutException) {
                    throw new ApiException(failure);
                }

                throw failure;
            }
        }, actorSystem.dispatcher());
```

and I'd like to be able to mimic that in a future composite block in java. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CompletableFuture#handle(BiFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-). For example

```
CompletableFuture<String> ask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
});
CompletableFuture<String> translatedException = ask.handle((r, e) -> {
    if (e != null) {
        if (e instanceof IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        // fallback
        if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException) e;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return r;
});
```

If `ask` completed with an exception, then `translatedException` will complete with a potentially transformed exception. Otherwise, it will have the same success result value.

Concerning my comment in the code, the `handle` method expects a `BiFunction` whose `apply` method is not declared to throw a `Throwable`. As such, the lambda body cannot itself throw a `Throwable`. The parameter `e` is of type `Throwable` so you can't `throw` it directly. You can cast it to `RuntimeException` if you know it's of that type, or you can wrap it in a `RuntimeException` and `throw` that.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that e will always be a `java.util.concurrent.CompletionException`.

```
CompletableFuture<String> ask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
});
CompletableFuture<String> translatedException = ask.handle((r, e) -> {
    if (e != null) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        throw (RuntimeException) e; // this is sketchy, handle it differently, maybe by wrapping it in a RuntimeException
    }
    return r;
});
```